# Change Bullets Style using Markdown

Tags: r-markdown

I am new to using Markdown.

Although I have managed to set a lot of styling options in the CSS,
I cannot figure out how to change the style of any bullets.

Regular ones :

- Regular Bullet

or

> - Block quote Bullet

and nested ones

> - Block quote Bullet 1
>
>   - Block quote Bullet 2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you are probably aware, Markdown's primary function is strictly as "markup" language so that a simple set of characters can remove the need for a lot of manual coding such as wrapping `<li></li>` on the front and back of your lists.

What Markdown isn't *really* meant for is styling that HTML for the final output. Some various subsets of Markdown include modifiers and things to make this happen but that can break if you have to change your markdown processor at some point.

That being said, you want to control this with CSS style, and that's done with this modifier:

```
list-style-type: square, disc, circle, etc...
```

Here's a list: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

If you are putting this on a page of other code consider that there may be some default styles already applied, so you may need to chain your CSS call with something like `ul li { list-style-type: your-choice}` to beat the overwrite — other than that, the above is the syntax you want.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible in GitHub Markdown like where I do change the CSS. Using raw html the attribute gets ignored. I.e. in English what does chain your css call mean?